# keep duplicate legendary heroes for tower garrison?

Tags: castle-clash

I have just received my 2nd paladin. Now you can't use 2 of the same heroes in battle, but i CAN garrison them both in towers.

Any advice on best move?  Should I keep them both or give huge amount of xp by consuming the 2nd one by my first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep both, with the pending [might rank update](http://us.forum.igg.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=98502&extra=page=1) you will be rewarded daily by increasing might. Besides you could get purple garrison which is good for the here be monsters raid.

Comment: Yeah I've definitely noticed how much stronger I am with monster raids. Towers with purple are very strong. Now have 2 pumpkin dukes and 2 paladins, lvl 80.  It cost very very very much to increase their skill all though ^^

Comment: What rank update btw?

Comment: It is an update where you are put into certain ranks where you are given daily rewards. The prizes increase as you get to higher classes